# Joel 2: From Eden to Ruination? To what is this referring?

Tags: exegesis, eden, joel

Joel Chapter 2:1-2.

> 1     Blow the trumpet in Zion;
>       sound the alarm on my holy hill.
>
> Let all who live in the land tremble,
>       for the day of the Lord is coming. It is close at hand— 2     a day of darkness and gloom,
>       a day of clouds and blackness. Like dawn spreading across the mountains
>       a large and mighty army comes, such as never was in ancient times
>       nor ever will be in ages to come.
>
> 3 Before them fire devours,
>       behind them a flame blazes. **Before them the land is like the garden of Eden,
>       behind them, a desert waste—
>       nothing escapes them.**

I find this scripture utterly amazing. It seems to be a last-days related scripture, and yet we have nothing on this earth resembling "the garden of Eden".

No doubt this had an initial fulfilment. To what nation did this apply, and did they have Eden-like conditions?

Comment: When you look at yields per acre now vs. then- trust me, out fields are the garden of Eden.

Comment: Still in what way does our earth resemble Eden? In reality only a few places come close.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know how fabulous the Garden of Eden was? There's no description of it where it appears, and we have many places on earth that are just "heavenly" to stroll through.

I believe the phrase is being used the same way we use it today to describe beautiful scenery.

If the location of this destruction is in Israel (scholars are not unified in a position on its location), you can see its lush greenery in these photos:
https://www.google.com/search?q=greenery+in+israel&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=X3q&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=sb&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=7ojnU7atOZTioATttYKoBg&ved=0CAYQ_AUoATgK&biw=1280&bih=566

So all that is beautiful in the land will be destroyed by a foreign invading army, which is left unspecified.

Answer (score -1):

This is referring to the day of the LORD.  A warning and a call to repentance. Continuing in the chapter;

Joel 2;11  And the LORD shall utter his voice before his army: for his camp is very great: for he is strong that executeth his word: for the day of the LORD is great and very terrible; and who can abide it?

Joel 2;32  And it shall come to pass, that whosoever shall call on the name of the LORD shall be delivered: for in mount Zion and in Jerusalem shall be deliverence, as the LORD has said, and in the remnant whom the LORD shall call.

Comment: You did not address the issue of Eden in your answer.